# Move Elastip IP from one account to another account

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-ip

Assume, I am having 2 accounts say Account A and B. Currently I am having a elastic IP in account A and assign it into a instance. Now I want to move the particular elastic IP from Account A to B. ie, release the particular elastic IP from Account A, and create the same elastic IP in Account B.

Is there a way to do it.? Anybody tried that?

Thanks in Advance.

Rahul.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way, try asking on the official forums; the moderators there may have more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can able to transfer the elastic ip to 1 account to another account pls follow the below steps

1. Dissociated and released the Elastic IP 0.0.0.0 from the source account.
2. Created a new IAM user for AWS CLI access and configured it for the Target account.
3. Ran the below command to allocate the Elastic IP to the Target account in ap-south-1 region.

   ## aws ec2 allocate-address --address 0.0.0.0
4. Now your old Ip will be unlocked in the destination account